# How to make CDK Angular stepper vertical

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk

Please, how can we change the orientation to vertical for the custom angular cdk stepper in this example provided by their site:

https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/examples

because I can't change it, even if i set the orientation to vertical it doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CDK Doesn't provide stylings

It's not possible to do it with just setting the `orientation` property. Component development kit (CDK) is just a collection of API's to help you build your own components and it's also used for the `@angular/material` library.

To check how the vertical `mat-stepper` works (it's based on the `cdkStepper`) you can check this [directory on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/material/stepper)

#### How to do it?

In case you want to make the `cdkStepper` vertical you will have to write your own `css` for it. If you need to switch between orientations you can use the property `orientation` for example in `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` as the `mat-stepper` does.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rkkppi?file=src/app/example-custom-stepper.css) is a very simple example of how you can do it based on the example from [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/examples)

```css
.example-step-navigation-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* <-- This is the added line  */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

### EDIT

To achieve the state that the content is next to the stepper you need to do few more change in css, set the `.container` to be flex, because it will put the elements in one row.

```css
.example-container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

and some HTML changes. We need to adjust the html to consist of two columns, we will achieve this by wrapping the content part into `div` with `.example-step-content` class.

```html
<section class="example-container">
  <div class="example-step-navigation-bar">
    <button class="example-nav-button" cdkStepperPrevious>&larr;</button>
    <button
      class="example-step"
      [class.example-active]="selectedIndex === i"
      *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index"
      (click)="selectStepByIndex(i)"
    >
      Step {{ i + 1 }}
    </button>
    <button class="example-nav-button" cdkStepperNext>&rarr;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="example-step-content">
    <header>
      <h2>Step {{ selectedIndex + 1 }}/{{ steps.length }}</h2>
    </header>

    <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected ? selected.content : null"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

With this modifications we have two columns, left with the stepper navigation bar and right with the content. I have also updated the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rkkppi-yyqzur?file=src/app/example-custom-stepper.html)

Comment: I already used this style, I wanted the header of the step and the content below, the example provided by angular is a complex one.

Comment: Okay, so you want the content to be next to the stepper itself and not above?

Comment: Yes please 

Comment: I have edited the answer, check if it's what you need.

Comment: I needed honestly the header of the step and below it the content as in material vertical stepper, but even this. it sounds better for responsiveness cuz that was my goal, to have the whole stepper wrapped on mobile, Thank you I really appreciate it 